# Combine yql auth.basic and ymail.messages to get yahoo emails?

Tags: yql

I have this:

```
    select * from auth.basic 
where url="mail.yahoo.com" 
and username="username" 
and password="password"
```

and this:

```
select * from ymail.messages where numMid='3'
```

Can I somehow combine them? I think you can imagine why I want this?

Answer (score 1):

The basic auth wont work with this table. The ymail.messages table supports OAuth so you can use 3 legged oauth described at http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/ and then use the oauth Authorization header to get the mail data from these tables.

Yahoo does support a couple of different languages including java and php. Let us know if you need a hand at that.